# Haxe+OpenFL app freezes when long-lasting loops used

Tags: loops, infinite-loop, haxe, openfl

So, the question is in the title. App freezes regardless of targeted platform when I make long-lasting loops. 
Third party loops also lead to freeze:

```
var s:Socket = new Socket();
var data:String; 
s.connect(new Host("localhost"), 5000);
s.waitForRead();
```

I can't make even a simple socket app, because it's main idea is to use long-lasting loops. When I'm not using OpenFL, everything goes OK. Should I manually reduce the CPU load inside the cycle and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps you're blocking the main thread (and thus, the game/app loop) with this `s.waitForRead()` call?  If that's the case, you could put this code in a separate thread or avoid blocking calls altogether (by polling from within other loops or using event-based APIs, if your target platform supports them).

Comment: @JonasMalacoFilho is right. AFAIK, OpenFL mimics Flash's 15 second loop limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[openfl.net.Socket](http://api.openfl.org/openfl/net/Socket.html) is probably what you're looking for - it extends [openfl.events.EventDispatcher](http://api.openfl.org/openfl/events/EventDispatcher.html), and thus utilizes an event-based API for handling listening/receiving data, etc., so it can be used **without blocking the main thread**.

So, an example of how one of these would be set up, might look something like this (lifted from [an OpenFL forum post](http://community.openfl.org/t/how-to-connect-to-a-server-using-openfl/7353))

```
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onResponse);
socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecError);
trace("Connecting to server.");
socket.connect("52.36.8.250", 443);
```

One thing to watch out for, it appears that `addEventListener`'s `listener` parameter is `Dynamic -> Void`, so using the value passed to the callback may be a little tricky.